# Parsing records with regex

Tags: regex

Is it possible to parse phone call records like the ones bellow with regex:

- 10/07   9:50A   555-111-2489      Peak M2MAllow   Anytown NJ   Georgetown DE  1  -- -- --
- 10/08  12:41P   555-111-2489  Off-Peak M2MAllow   My Town DE   Georgetown DE 15  -- -- --
- 10/11  11:50A   000-000-0086      Peak PlanAllow,CallVM  Anytown NJ  Voice Mail CL 1 -- -- --

Comment: Probably - what do you need from each row?

Comment: is it a normal file? then `awk` is best as they are delimited by space (` `)

Comment: Please explain the question better. What do you need to parse it for? Are you trying to get something from each record? What should the end result be?

Comment: I need to split all the fields: Date, time, phone, peak/off-peak, call type, origin, destination, duration, charges, other charges, total

Comment: What is ",CallVM" in the middle of the bottom entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what you want, probably? That said, it's very likely that a regular expression is the Wrong Tool For The Job.

At a glance, it looks like you want something like this - split on spaces the first 5 entries, and the last 5, and everything else is free text. So, in perl, say, it'd look something like this:

```
while (<>) {
  my ($date, $time, $number, $peak, $plan, @rest) = split ' ', $_;
  # do something with this information
}
```

But without actually knowing what you are trying to do, this is all just a fancy guess.

Comment: 10/07     9:49A              000-000-0086             Peak     PlanAllow,CallVM                                Anytown NJ            Voice Mail CL               1            --                  --            --

Comment: Um, okay, that's another line. What about it?